# Rendezvous Orbits

Tags: orbital-motion, space

If I have two orbits, Orbit 1 and Orbit 2, and the spacecraft with Orbit 2 is trying to dock with the spacecraft in Orbit 1, but does not have a stable orbit (it will crash into Earth) how will this affect Orbit 1's orbit? Here's a simple diagram.
[image: Orbiting Diagram]

**So how does the rendezvous effect Orbit 1? Will this make Orbit 1 shrink, or would it stay the same (or something else)?**

Comment: Is there any interaction between the spacecrafts in orbit 1 and 2, such as crashing into each other, or cancelling relative velocity? Because currently it is not clear what you are asking and what you have tried yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Orbit 2 makes rendezvous with Orbit 1, it is travelling more slowly than Orbit 1 (which is why, if it misses rendezvous, it will then drop to a lower altitude and reenter). So there are two possibilities for the rendezvous.

1) Just before joining up with #1, #2 fires rockets to gain speed to match with #1. In this case, the two conjoined ships will continue in Orbit 1.

2) #2 does not speed up, and the two ships collide. Assuming that they survive this collision, and they fuse together, and their masses are approximately equal, the new composite vehicle will have a velocity which is the average of the two original velocities, and an orbit sort of like #2's original Orbit 2. However, the new orbit will not approach the earth quite as closely at perigee. If Orbit 2 just grazed the earth, the new orbit will miss earth entirely.

Comment: So to successfully rendezvous (and not crash), they must be in an equal orbit (#2 would have the same orbit as #1)?